# Non-Resourceful Routes and POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Right now I'm trying to write my own custom Rails routes for my app, but for some reason, when I write in non-resourceful routes, I cannot get POST requests (or anything besides GET for that matter) to route to the action that I specified.  I tried using the via keyword, and tried using the conditions hash, but when I run rake routes I do not see the POST method show up next to the route.

Here's the code:

```
#config/routes.rb

get "transactions/:id/process", :to => "transactions#payment", :as => :transaction_process,:via => [:get, :post], :conditions => {:method => :post }
```

I tried using only via, and only conditions, and neither of those work.  I have a form that I send to this action, but I get the error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/transactions/8/process"
```

Does anybody have any idea how I can get Rails to route POST requests to this URL to my transaction#payment action?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `get` method in your route is declaring a single route, which in this case is a GET request. If you want to define both a custom GET and a POST in one line, you can use `match`.

From the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints):

match 'photos/show' => 'photos#show', :via => [:get, :post]